# How to enable ligatures with `space` inside?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, spacing, ligature

I relased a new version of [PragmataPro](https://fsd.it/shop/fonts/pragmatapro/) typeface and now I'm sure that ligatures with `space` character like `|\ \ \` `/ / /|` `[INFO ]` `[PASS ]` are ignored in IDEs like VS Code.
Could you let me know how `space` character in ligatures is handled in VS Code please?
Is there a way to enable ligatures with `space` inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution: VS Code use `nbspace` as space character for ligatures

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126143